# Does $|z_1+z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|\implies z_1=kz_2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb C$. I was wondering if

> $$|z_1+z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|\implies z_1=k z_2\ \ or\ \ z_2=0,\quad k\in\mathbb R^+.$$

Is it true?

I am having problems trying to show it. I'm sure it's easy to show using brute force, but if it's true, is there an elegant way to show it?

Comment: Should it be $k\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$?

Comment: Not true. Consider $z_1=1$ and $z_2=0$.

Comment: @lostlife and thus $z_2=0 z_1$.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey : I in fact need $\iff$, but $\Leftarrow$ is obvious.

Comment: @lostlife 0 = 0 x 1 and = $\in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. It is equivalent to $z_1=\lambda z_2$ or $z_2=\lambda z_1$, $\;\lambda \in \mathbf R_+$, or, if they're both non-zero, to the fact that $z_1$ and $z_2$  have the same argument.

To prove it, we may suppose both are non-zero. So set $z_k=r_k\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \theta_k}, \enspace k=1,2$. Squaring both sides, we have to check under which conditions we have
\begin{align*}&(r_1\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \theta_1}+r_2\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \theta_2})(r_1\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \theta_1}+r_2\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \theta_2})=(r_1+r_2)^2\\
\iff& r_1^2+r_2^2+r_1r_2\bigl(\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}\bigr)=(r_1+r_2)^2\\
\iff&\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}=2.
\end{align*}
Setting $u=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}$, this means $$u+u^{-1}=2\iff u=1\iff\theta_1-\theta_2\equiv 0\mod 2\pi\iff\theta_1\equiv\theta_2\equiv0\mod 2\pi.$$

Comment: Or $z_2=0$ ;)..

Comment: I edit my question, I wanted to say $k\in\mathbb R$ (because I think it can be negatif). But how can you show the equivalence elegantly ?

Comment: @user330587 It can't be negative (i.e. $z_1=-1$ and $z=1$), but your statement is still true because $k \in \Bbb{R}^{\geq 0} \implies k \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Thanks I edited my question

Comment: @N. S.: Right. I meant  there must such a linear relation between them. It might as well be $z_2$ in function of $z_1$.

Comment: You should use the intermediate step $e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}=e^{-i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}=1$ before the end to make this more clear.

Comment: @Noble Mushtak: You're  right. I've added some more details.

Answer (score 6):

Squaring both sides, we see this is equivalent to:

$$(z_1+z_2)(\overline z_1+\overline z_2)=z_1\overline z_1 + 2|z_1||z_2| + z_2\overline z_2$$

which is equivalent to:

$$\mathrm{Re}(z_1\overline z_2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(z_1\overline z_2+z_2\overline z_1\right)=|z_1 \overline z_2|$$

So $z_1\overline z_2=\alpha$ must be  non-negative real. Then you get:

$$z_1|z_2|^2 = \alpha z_2$$

So either $z_2=0$ or $z_1=\frac{\alpha}{|z_2|^2}z_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate solution using the Law of Cosines. If we say $z_1=\lvert z_1\rvert\text{cis} \ \theta_1$ and $z_2=\lvert z_2\rvert\text{cis} \ \theta_2$, then:
$$\lvert z_1+z_2 \rvert^2=\lvert z_1\rvert^2+\lvert z_2\rvert^2-2\lvert z_1 \rvert\lvert z_2\rvert\cos(\pi-(\theta_2-\theta_1))$$
Thus, by squaring both sides of $\lvert z_1+z_2 \rvert=\lvert z_1\rvert+\lvert z_2\rvert$, we get:
$$\lvert z_1+z_2 \rvert^2=\lvert z_1\rvert^2+\lvert z_2\rvert^2+2\lvert z_1\rvert\lvert z_2\rvert$$
$$\lvert z_1\rvert^2+\lvert z_2\rvert^2-2\lvert z_1 \rvert\lvert z_2\rvert\cos(\pi-(\theta_2-\theta_1))=\lvert z_1\rvert^2+\lvert z_2\rvert^2+2\lvert z_1\rvert\lvert z_2\rvert$$
Subtract both sides by $\lvert z_1\rvert^2+\lvert z_2\rvert^2$:
$$-2\lvert z_1 \rvert\lvert z_2\rvert\cos(\pi-(\theta_2-\theta_1))=2\lvert z_1\rvert\lvert z_2\rvert$$
Divde both sides by $2\lvert z_1 \rvert\lvert z_2\rvert$:
$$-\cos(\pi-(\theta_2-\theta_1))=1$$
Multiply both sides by $-1$:
$$\cos(\pi-(\theta_2-\theta_1))=-1$$
Take the $\arccos$ of both sides:
$$\pi-(\theta_2-\theta_1)=\pi+2\pi n$$
Solve for $\theta_2-\theta_1$:
$$\theta_2-\theta_1=2\pi n$$
Thus, we have:
$$\theta_2=\theta_1+2\pi n$$
This means $z_2=\lvert z_2 \rvert\text{cis} \ (\theta_1+2\pi n)=\lvert z_2 \rvert \text{cis} \ \theta_1$. Thus: $$z_2=\frac{\lvert z_2 \rvert}{\lvert z_1 \rvert}z_1$$
Clearly, $\frac{\lvert z_2 \rvert}{\lvert z_1 \rvert} \in \Bbb{R}^{\geq 0}$, so we are done.